# Can any one help me HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css

**I want Text Box for my blogger in which i can post Html - CSS codes and user's can copy them.** Example = [The Image Link](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OhvKmLgY-O4/UnaA9HGfcVI/AAAAAAAAA3Y/b4VrxT8BK8U/s1600/Long+code.png)

**The Image That i want to use** = [image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-i3AX6FFu9N8/UnYbGgMgYhI/AAAAAAAAA2k/SFv0kK7x6YI/s1600/Coding+Place+For+Blogger.png)

**I want that If the code is small. It should automatically become like this** = [Image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RYmQ9CRKiVw/UnaAv0niNuI/AAAAAAAAA3Q/2Fi6bRvkUUg/s1600/small+code.png)

**and If the code is long, it should automatically be like this** = [Image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OhvKmLgY-O4/UnaA9HGfcVI/AAAAAAAAA3Y/b4VrxT8BK8U/s1600/Long+code.png)

**When i try to make it and i paste the code in it, it become horrible, you can see** = [Looking Very Bad](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CP8_CBwHwMk/UnZ33pJdhEI/AAAAAAAAA2w/8e8mZUsAwRo/s1600/solution+please.png)

***My CSS CODE:***

```
#tbox1 {
    background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-i3AX6FFu9N8/UnYbGgMgYhI/AAAAAAAAA2k/SFv0kK7x6YI/s1600/Coding+Place+For+Blogger.png) no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:380px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px 40px;
    overflow:auto;
    word-wrap:nowrap;
    /*font styles*/
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    /*1em*/
    color:#000000;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="tbox1">Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code v</div>
```

*You can see on JsFiddle that what's actually happening to me*
http://jsfiddle.net/e5nHr/

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the issue? the question is not clear. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to have flexible height u must remove border from image in background and insert it in css code.

```
border: 4px solid #000;
border-radius: 1em;
```

That that: http://jsfiddle.net/fUaXL/

Answer (score 0):

use this code : [http://jsfiddle.net/e5nHr/8/]

The other problem is that you are using a wrong image, you should just use the Orange part of image and do the edge with css codes